# I am trying to create a store_transaction and change the Blockchain by passing a value

Tags: transactions, ether, web3.py, ganache, sendtransaction

I am trying to create a store_transaction that is later on signed and sent and trying to receive a transaction receipt. I am getting error while creating a store transaction while trying to build it. I have gone through few forums and folks have indicated issue with version of ganache

Below is my code:

```
from gettext import install
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
from web3 import Web3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# from sympy import source
import json

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()
    print(simple_storage_file)

install_solc("0.6.6")

compile_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    }
)

with open("compile_sol.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compile_sol, file)


# get bytecode

bytecode = compile_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]

# get abi

abi = compile_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]

# for connecting to gnache

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://0.0.0.0:7545"))
chain_id = 1337

# This address and private key will change via ganache everytime this gets executed as this is temp
my_address = "0x8f00e937573cDC71A3cCF3E7FFdF749f072007D7"
# private_key = "12912dc68f4ce8f49c876adee0cad218eb0bae59213190444095eda7cc8a1af8"
private_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")

# Create the contract in Python
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
# Get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
# Submit the transaction that deploys the contract

print(nonce)

print("no erros so far")

# Build a transaction
# Sign a transaction
# Send a transaction

transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)

# print(transaction)

signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
print(signed_txn)

tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
tx_reciept = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)

# working with contract
# contract address
# contract abi

simple_storage = w3.eth.contract(address=tx_reciept.contractAddress, abi=abi)

# call -> simulate making a call just to interact with BlockChain
# transact -> make a state change, to interact with BlockChain and make a state change

# initial value of favorite number
print(simple_storage.functions.retrieve().call())
print(simple_storage.functions.store(15).call())

##Code fails at this point
store_transaction = simple_storage.functions.store(15).buildTransaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id, 
        "from": my_address, 
        "nonce": nonce + 1
    }
)

signed_store_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
    store_transaction, private_key=private_key
)

send_store_trx = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_store_txn.rawTransaction)
tx_reciept = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(send_store_trx)

print('printing the transaction reciept')
print(tx_reciept)


Part that is failing here is :
store_transaction = simple_storage.functions.store(15).buildTransaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id, 
        "from": my_address, 
        "nonce": nonce + 1
    }
)
```

ERRORStack I get is:

```
/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/eth.py:633: UserWarning: There was an issue with the method eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas. Calculating using eth_feeHistory.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 631, in max_priority_fee
    return self._max_priority_fee()
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 171, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'message': 'Method eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas not supported.', 'code': -32000, 'data': {'stack': 'Error: Method eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas not supported.\n    at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/geth_api_double.js:70:16)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at GethDefaults.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/gethdefaults.js:15:12)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.FilterSubprovider.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/filters.js:89:7)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/subscriptions.js:137:49)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at DelayedBlockFilter.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/delayedblockfilter.js:31:3)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at RequestFunnel.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/requestfunnel.js:32:12)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at Web3ProviderEngine._handleAsync (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:123:3)\n    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:107:12)\n    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)\n    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)', 'name': 'Error'}}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deploy.py", line 98, in <module>
    store_transaction = simple_storage.functions.store(15).buildTransaction(
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1079, in buildTransaction
    return build_transaction_for_function(
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1648, in build_transaction_for_function
    prepared_transaction = fill_transaction_defaults(web3, prepared_transaction)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py", line 114, in fill_transaction_defaults
    default_val = default_getter(web3, transaction)
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py", line 64, in <lambda>
    web3.eth.max_priority_fee + (2 * web3.eth.get_block('latest')['baseFeePerGas'])
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 637, in max_priority_fee
    return fee_history_priority_fee(self)
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/_utils/fee_utils.py", line 45, in fee_history_priority_fee
    fee_history = eth.fee_history(*PRIORITY_FEE_HISTORY_PARAMS)  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 863, in fee_history
    return self._fee_history(block_count, newest_block, reward_percentiles)
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "/Users/svarpe/Desktop/BlockchainLearning/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 171, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'message': 'Method eth_feeHistory not supported.', 'code': -32000, 'data': {'stack': 'Error: Method eth_feeHistory not supported.\n    at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/geth_api_double.js:70:16)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at GethDefaults.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/gethdefaults.js:15:12)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.FilterSubprovider.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/filters.js:89:7)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/subscriptions.js:137:49)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at DelayedBlockFilter.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/delayedblockfilter.js:31:3)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at RequestFunnel.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/requestfunnel.js:32:12)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at Web3ProviderEngine._handleAsync (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:123:3)\n    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:107:12)\n    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)\n    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)', 'name': 'Error'}}
```

Comment: I figured out the problem and I was missing the <"gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,> in the transaction which changed after EIP1559 and it became mandatory to add that one. For some reason i missed that one in store transaction

Comment: Hi Sameer! If you solved your own question you can add the fix as an answer, so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Add gas price in the transaction.

```
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction( {
"gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price, 
"chainId": chain_id, 
"from": my_address, 
"nonce": nonce}
```

Answer (score 0):

THE Fix :

```
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction({
    "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price, 
    "chainId": chain_id, 
    "from": my_address, 
    "nonce": nonce
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the video's I have been following there is no gas price, but it looks like gas price is required.

```
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().build_transaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
```

on the Github repo it is corrected